Grammarly adjusts SpannableStringBuilder
I develop organizer application for Android. I use SpannableStringBuilder for setting different styles for text in EditText. While testing on sasmung A34 I faced with following issue:
Grammarly adjusts Spannable String while spell checking.
For examle I had following string <p dir="ltr"><b>Good morning sir </b></p> but Grammarly adjusts it to <p dir="ltr"><b><b>Good </b></b><b><b>morning sir</b></b><b><b><b> </b></b></b></p>
I found some recommendation but it's not resolve my problem.
For example I used inputTypes TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS, TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_COMPLETE, TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_AUTO_CORRECT but issue is still reproduced. Unexpected spans (tags) have been added to the SpannableStringBuilder.
